# What is the difference between a balanced binary search tree and a binary search tree?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

Sorry if this is an extremely basic question, but I am fairly new to trees and hence, this doubt bothers me these days.

What is the difference between a binary search tree and a balanced binary search tree? Isn't every BST (Binary search tree) already a BBST (Balanced BST)?

Comment: See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015630/definition-of-a-balanced-tree) for a good discussion of balanced binary trees.

Answer (score 3):

"Balanced" is a property that a binary tree may have. It generally means that each node in the tree has approximately the same number of descendant nodes on each subtree underneath it. It more specifically means that the "height" of the tree has been minimized.

For a tree that is not "Balanced", it is possible to have a binary tree where all the "left" child nodes are null, and it still otherwise has the properties of a "binary search tree".  This is called a degenerate tree, as it is structurally more like a Linked List, and therefore would have O(N) search time instead of O(log(N)).

Comment: Basically, in layman terms, can I say that a balanced tree is one where the height of the left and right subtrees differ by at most 1? And in BST, this might not necessarily be true?

Comment: That is "necessary but not sufficient".  It must include where "every sub-tree is also a balanced tree"

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that a balance binary tree has the possibly minimum height