# Number of possible balanced binary trees?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Given number of nodes N (ie a preorder seq of length N) in a balanced binary tree,I am trying to find the number `b` of possible balanced binary trees that can be formed.

I noticed it is possible that there might be variations in the leaves as well as the higher-level nodes:

```
         A
       /   \
      B     C  
     /     / \  
    D     E   F  
         /  
        G
```

The constraint is generally applied recursively to every subtree. That is, the tree is only balanced if:

1.The left and right subtrees' heights differ by at most one, AND
2.The left subtree is balanced, AND
3.The right subtree is balanced

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please define "balanced tree".

Comment: Done! I am taking the example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015630/definition-of-a-balanced-tree

Comment: Are two balanced trees considered to be the same tree if one is formed by relabelling the vertices of the other? Are they the same tree if one is formed by exchanging the left and right subtrees of the other?

Comment: The actual question actually says a preorder seq of n is there.So no one can not do that.Let me correct the q.Thanks