# Confusion in terminology while defining Balanced Binary Tree: Height of a subtree vs. Height of a node

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal, recursive-datastructures

Referencing the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015630/definition-of-a-balanced-tree)

A balanced binary tree is:

1. The left and right subtrees' heights differ by at most one, AND
2. The left subtree is balanced, AND
3. The right subtree is balanced

Now, using the same example

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C  
 /     / \  
D     E   F  
     /  
    G
```

The tree is rooted at A.

Now, when looking at the definition for height balanced tree, the first point says:

1. The left and right subtrees' heights differ by at most one

   If I am currently at the node A, to determine the height of the LEFT SUBTREE of A I am confused if I calculate:

   - Height of node A looking at the deepest left child from A (D)      OR
   - Height of node B looking at the deepest left child from A (by extension B) (D)

   If I am currently at the node A, to determine the height of the RIGHT SUBTREE of A I am confused if I calculate:

   - Height of node A looking at the deepest right child from A (F)      OR
   - Height of node C looking at the deepest right child from A (by extension C) (F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'The height of a subtree' is generally translated as 'height of the root of the subtree'. Bumped into this explanation while listening to this [MIT OpenCourseWare lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNeL18KsWPc&t=1s), at timestamp 13:17.